# Flutter Firebase Posts that user like system

Tags: flutter

```
  void _setpostlike() async {
final _uid=ref!.uid;
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("posts").doc (widget.postId).update({
  "like": FieldValue.arrayUnion([
    FirebaseAuth
        .instance
        .currentUser!
        .uid,
  ])

});
```

}
I can add a user id to the post. What I can't do is print a text of the total likes.
Or is there a more practical way of the rating system.
I want to call back and print how many likes it has on a text.
Thanks for reading, best regards.

Comment: Can i see you firestore structure? A screenshot would do.

Comment: I sent you sir. https://i.hizliresim.com/6iel236.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.